# ruby : return object if test is true

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I'm looking for a function that would do the following:

```
def self.my_find
  object = self.first #Whatever
  return object.my_check? ? object : nil
end
```

Something like `check`:

```
object.check(&:my_check?)
```

It should exist, shouldn't it?

Here's my situation:

In a method (controller), I have some `nil`-able objects and I need to check something on the object to further use it.

In the event of trying to write pseudo-functional code, the logic is first to retrieve the objects, then making actions on the objects and then return those.

If I have a collection, the code would be:

```
result = get_my_collection_method.select(&:my_check?).map(&:my_action)
```

There is no issue if the `select` methods filters all objects, then `result` will equal `[]` but the code is still valid.

I find natural to wanting to do the same even if it is not a collection but a single object:

```
result = get_my_object.check(&:my_check?).try(:my_action)
```

But the fact that this method doesn't exist tells me there is no monadic transformation between object and array in ruby.

I guess the simplest way to achieve this is that I transform my singleton into a single value array:

```
result = Array(get_my_object).select(&:my_check?).map(&:my_action).first
```

I hope this clarifies *why* I was looking for such method.

But the question remains: does it exist natively? If I write it myself (even at the `Object` level), this is not standard, I lose the benefits of writing clean code.

Comment: `object if object.my_check?`

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

While a method like that might seem useful in your particular circumstance, this sort of thing is generally expressed like:

```
object = self.first
object.my_check? and object
```

Where it's understood that this method may return `false` but that's not a logically true value so it's fine.

If you want to write your own method for Object that does this, you're welcome to, but keep in mind the more esoteric and quirky your code is the harder it will be for other people to engage with. Those "other people" might be you in the future when you've forgotten about your unusual core extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few ways:

```
def self.my_find
  object = self.first # Whatever

  # Use ONE of the following examples:

  # 1.
  object if object.my_check?

  # 2.
  object.my_check? && object

  # 3.
  object.my_check? ? object : nil
end
```

Note that an explicit `return` is not needed at the end of a method in ruby.

Depending on the context though (I can only speculate, as none was given!), there *might* be a cleaner way to do this. For example, if this is actually something you're building in a rails application, then one of these examples would be better:

```
def self.my_find
  where(...).find_by(my_check: true)

  # Or, where `my_check` is a *SCOPE*!!
  my_check.find_by(...)
end
```

...With the key difference being that you're performing the check *in SQL* rather than in ruby. This gives better performance.